# How dns resolve root-servers.net

Tags: networking, dns

As I know there is 13 root dns server in the world which named from **A** to **M**.
and when no dns server answered in dns server chain,we access root dns servers.

I also suppose root server should be ip address something like 4.4.2.2 or 8.8.8.8 but using dig show me they're really domains

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
.           78559   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           78559   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
```

Now how DNS resolve **root-servers.net** address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those root servers are defined in the config file of the DNS server, most run BIND and it's in the config file root.servers

Internic constantly provides the most up-to-date one, which is currently (both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses):

```
a.root-servers.net. IN  A   198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:503:BA3E::2:30

b.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.228.79.201

c.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.33.4.12

d.root-servers.net. IN  A   199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:500:2d::d

e.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.203.230.10

f.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:500:2f::f

g.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.112.36.4

h.root-servers.net. IN  A   128.63.2.53
h.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:500:1::803f:235

i.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:7fe::53

j.root-servers.net. IN  A   192.58.128.30
j.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:503:C27::2:30

k.root-servers.net. IN  A   193.0.14.129
k.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:7fd::1

l.root-servers.net. IN  A   199.7.83.42
l.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:500:3::42

m.root-servers.net. IN  A   202.12.27.33
m.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA    2001:dc3::35
```

Answer (score 1):

DNS resolvers come with a *root hints file* (see http://www.internic.net/domain/named.root) built-in -- as part of their configuration -- which lists the names and IPs of the root DNS servers.

By the way, that's the same principle with SSL/TLS certificate validation in your browser - the browser traverses the certificate chain up to validate a website's SSL/TLS certificate -- potentially downloading multiple intermediate certificate authority (CA) certificates -- but the root CA certificates come pre-installed with the browser.

In general and in other terms, when there's a recursive process involved you must define a base case. Otherwise you have an endless loop.